# Computer screen spontaneously turns white and stays white even after computer shutdown

Tags: gpu, overheating

Today I put some heavy load on my GPU, then the screen went white. I turned the computer off, but it stayed like this until I restarted the monitor itself.

1. Why is the monitor behaving like this? If the computer is off, there should be no signal coming to it. Also, the whiteness was increasing steadily with time, not diminishing. It could have lasted forever if I hadn't restarted the monitor.
   I booted the computer up again and after 5 minutes of very light load on the GPU the same thing happened.
2. I understand that high load + very high room temperature (which was my case) can potentionally kill hardware. I am almost sure I broke something in the GPU. Why is it working then? And if it's not broken, why is it doing the same thing again?

*I am talking about a desktop environment here:
Monitor: LG 19LS4R (crappy thing)
GPU: AMD R9 200 series.
The cooling in the case is not very good. The CPU sink and the second cooler on the video card (cooling the vram) are so close together, that no fresh air goes into the video RAM.

Sorry guys, my computer was able to boot just 2 more times before it failed completely - it won't even start. This is another topic though. Thank you all for the suggestions, but I won't be able to try them out without a PC. I think the topic is good and will benefit the community in some way - so don't stop giving suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning all-white is a sign of a failed monitor.

[Example](http://www.laptoprepair101.com/laptop-lcd-screen-turned-white/)

What to try:

- Try a new video cable (ensure it's attached properly/securely on both ends).

If it still acts up:

- Try the monitor on another computer.

If it still acts up, it's definitely the monitor, and replacing is probably cheapest/easiest.